# How to create a procedure which checks if there are any recently added records to the table and if there are then move them to archive table

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have to create a procedure which searches any recently added records and if there are then move them to ARCHIVE table.
This is my statement which filters recently added records

SELECT

```
   CL_ID,
   CL_NAME,
   CL_SURNAME,
   CL_PHONE,
   VEH_ID,
   VEH_REG_NO,
   VEH_MODEL,
   VEH_MAKE_YEAR,
   WD_ID,
   WORK_DESC,
   INV_ID,
   INV_SERIES,
   INV_NUM,
   INV_DATE,
   INV_PRICE
```

FROM

```
  CLIENT,
  INVOICE,
  VEHICLE,
  WORKS,
  WORKS_DONE
```

WHERE

```
  Client.CL_ID=Invoice.INV_CL_ID and
  Invoice.INV_CL_ID = Client.CL_ID and
  Client.CL_ID = Vehicle.VEH_CL_ID and
  Vehicle.VEH_ID = Works_Done.WD_VEH_ID and
  Works_done.WD_INV_ID = Invoice.INV_ID and
  WORKS_DONE.WD_WORK_ID = Works.WORK_ID and
  Works_done. Timestamp >= sysdate -1;
```

Comment: Is the question: "how do I create a procedure", or "how do I find the records that are not in this list", or "how do I efficiently move records from one table to another" ... ?

Comment: "how do I efficiently move records from one table to another" i need to create a procedure for that

Comment: Do you know how to create a PL/SQL procedure? If not, that is your first question.

Comment: Yes i know how to create a procedure

Comment: What i don't understand is how i can move those records which my statements find to another table, if there are any records to move. If there aren't then do nothing...

Comment: So it may be more of a "what sort of approach should I use?", or more of a "what is the exact SQL"?

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this (pseudo-code):

```
create or replace procedure moveRecords is
    vLimitDate timestamp := systimestamp -1;
begin
    insert into table2
    select *
    from table1
    where your_date >= vLimitDate;
    --
    delete table1
    where your_date >= vLimitDate;
end;
```

Comment: okay, thank!!! I don't need to delete records from Table1 i just need to move them

Answer (score 0):

O.K. may be something like this...

The downside is - it can be slow for large tables.

The upside is that there is no dependence on date and time - so you can run it anytime and synchronize your archives with live data...

```
create or replace procedure archive is
begin
    insert into archive_table 
    (
    select * from main_table 
    minus 
    select * from archive_table
    );
end;
```

Comment: No i need to create a procedure

Comment: @Mairis if it can be done with sql - it sure can be done with plsql - here you go - I changed my solution a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I've used for this sort of task in the past.

1. Create a global temporary table (GTT) to hold a set of ROWIDs
2. Perform a multitable direct path insert, which selects the rows to be archived from the source table and inserts their ROWIDs into the GTT and the rest of the data into the archive table.
3. Perform a delete from the source table, where the source table ROWID is in the GTT of rowids
4. Issue a commit.

The business with the GTT and the ROWIDs ensures that you have 100% guaranteed stability in the set of rows that you are selecting and then deleting from the source table, regardless of any changes that might occur between the start of your select and the start of your delete (other than someone causing a partitioned table row migration or shrinking the table).

You could alternatively achieve that through changing the transaction isolation level.